# Is it possible to run CSOM code to cancel workflows? (SP 2013 )

Tags: 2013, workflow, powershell, csom, client-object-model

I have the following code from previous job and it worked perfectly b/c I was the SP admin and had SP Server access. Now I dont have SP server access.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://inside.nov.com"
$list = $web.Lists["ONMS Documents"]
    
foreach ($item in $list.Items)
 {
   foreach ($wf in $item.Workflows)
     {
     #Check for the particular workflow
        if($wf.InternalState -match 'Error')
        {  
            #Cancel Workflow
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::CancelWorkflow($wf)                 
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What level of access do you have?

Comment: I am in the SCA for this particular site.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this post but not sure if it's gonna work with SP 2013 on-prem.

Source: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/cancelling-the-sharepoint-online-workflows-using-csom

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$siteURL = "http://siteURL.com/"   
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL) 

$userId = "ID12345"   
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString   
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userId, $pwd)   
$ctx.credentials = $creds   
$web= $ctx.web   

try  
{  
  #Provide the List or Library name which contains Workflow  
    $list = $ctx.web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestListWorkFlow")  
    $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true  
    foreach($listItem in $list.Items) {  
        foreach($workflow in $listItem.Workflows)  
        {  
          #Completed Workflows has to be ignored  
            if (($listItem.Workflows | where {  
                    $_.InternalState - ne "Completed"  
                }) - ne $null)  
            {  
              #Stop / Cancel the Workflows[Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::CancelWorkflow($workflow) write - output $listItem.Title "Workflow has been stopped” -foregroundcolor green   
            }  
        }  
    }  
    $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false  
} catch {  
    write - host "$($_.Exception.Message)" - foregroundcolor red  
}
```

Comment: Could you add this to your question rather than as an answer (unless it is the answer to your problem, if so, you can mark it as the answer).

Comment: The answer I posted doesn't work with SharePoint 2013 on-prem. Can anyone suggest ?